# Space between slider and header?

Tags: css

Hi I have a test page up here http://blueanchorcreative.com/

There is a little tiny gap between the slider and the header and I can't figure out what it is? I tried applying overflow hidden to the header but that jacked up the rest of the page and I couldn't figure out how to make that work! Please help a newbie!

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code *directly* into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOOK AT THE VALUE:

```
#slideshow > div {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px; // this value to 0px
}
```

Comment: Well I feel foolish. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove `top: 10px` value from the rule:

```
#slideshow > div {
   top: 0;
}
```

It's at the line **195** of http://blueanchorcreative.com/style.css